# How to remove repeated characters but keeping on? Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove repeating characters but keeping one of them in a word for consonant letters.

I wrote following code but it deletes all of them.

```
import re
text = "myyyy nname isss ssevvaall"
new = re.sub(r"([a-z])(\1{2,})","",text)
```

Result should be

> my name is sevvaal

Comment: Why should double `v` and `a` not be removed from `sevvaal` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want exceptional behavior for `v` and `a` char then use this regex,

```
([^\W\d_va])(?=\1)
```

And remove it with empty string

Here `[^\W\d_va]` means all alphabets except `v` and `a`

[Demo where v and a letter is exempted](https://regex101.com/r/JzkYIN/1)

You can also write `[^\W\d_va]` as `[b-uw-zB-UW-Z]`

If you want to write in your style without using lookahead, you can use following regex,

```
([^\W\d_va])\1+
```

And replace it with `$1` or `\1` where the regex will match a character if it appears more than once and will replace it with single character

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/85Y8jE/1)

Comment: `[^\W\d_va]` means all word forming characters except digits, low line , v, and a. It does not mean all alphabetic characters except v and a. IN Unicode 15.0 there are 137765 alphabetic characters. With a Unicode compliant regex engine `[^\W\d_]` will match 1114109 characters. For Python's re module  `[^\W\d_]` should match around 981224, so in either case, its matching much more than just alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the character set a-z, using capture groups you you might either replace 3 or more consecutive characters with a single one, or match 2 consecutive consonants not followed by a vowel and replace with a single one.

The notations `\1` `\2` and `\3` are backreferences to match the same character that is captured in the group.

```
([a-z])\1{2,}|([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])\2(?!([aeiou])\3)
```

The pattern matches:

- `([a-z])\1{2,}` Match 3 or more of the same consecutive characters, capturing the first in **group 1**
- `|` Or
- `([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])\2` Match 2 of the same consonants capturing the first in **group 2**
- `(?!([aeiou])\3)` Assert not 2 of the same vowels using a negative lookahead, capturing the first in **group 3**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LRje7X/1)

```
import re

text = "myyyy nname isss ssevvaall"
pattern = r"([a-z])\1{2,}|([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])\2(?!([aeiou])\3)"
new = re.sub(pattern, r"\1\2", text)
print(new)
```

Output

```
my name is sevvaal
```